# For the MSP432, does it matter what counting mode is used to generate a particular frequency PWM?

Tags: microcontroller, msp432

I know there are 3 counting modes, up, continuous and up/down.

Let’s say if I intend to generate a 5Hz, 50% duty cycle PWM as output in the compare mode,

As long as I choose the appropriate output mode such as toggle or toggle/reset, I should get the same result of 5Hz 50% duty cycle PWM right?

Comment: In general the only differences are when you change the frequency or the duty cycle, if these are fixed there is not difference.  (So long, as you say, you match the modes and output modes and so on.)